# How to launch the associated application for a file / directory / URL?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, cross-platform, shellexecute

**Linux** seems to be easy: `xdg-open <file/directory/URL>`.

Apparently, **Mac** is similar: `open` should be used instead of `xdg-open`. I don't have access to a Mac so I couldn't test it.

For **Windows**, I found 4 different suggestions and those that I have tried failed.

- [Is there a non-java, cross platform way to launch the associated application for a certain file type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1480971/341970)
  suggests 
  `start`
- [How to give focus to default program of shell-opened file, from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2765823/341970) suggests 
  `cmd /c start ...`
- [How to open user system preferred editor for given file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/526037/341970)
  [How to Find Out Default File Opener with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2211209/341970)
  suggest  
   `RUNDLL32.exe`
- [What is the correct way to use ShellExecute() in C to open a .txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11007537/341970)
  [Open file with Windows' native program within C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5127249/341970)
  [How to use ShellExecute to open html files in Windows using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10737854/341970) suggest 
  `ShellExecute`

I have tried the first 3 with `system()` and `QProcess::startDetached()` and `"http://www.stackoverflow.com"` as argument but they all failed; `start` works just fine from the command line though. I haven't tried `ShellExecute` yet.

**What is the Windows equivalent of `xdg-open`?** It seem to me, it is `start` but why did my attempts with `start` fail?

**Is `ShellExecute` my only option?**

---

**EDIT** I thought `QDesktopServices::openUrl()` was for web pages only because it did not work for files or directories.

After some debugging I figured out that if I replace `\\` with `/` in the path on Windows, it works for files but the directories are still not opened. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
QDir dir("C:/Documents and Settings/ali");

qDebug() << "Exists? " << dir.exists();

qDebug() << dir.absolutePath();

QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(dir.absolutePath()));

qDebug() << "External app called";
```

Application Output:

```
Exists?  true 
"C:/Documents and Settings/ali" 
External app called
```

But nothing happens, the directory is not opened. On Linux, directories are opened with the default file manager as expected.

---

**SOLUTION:** Due to the Qt bug *and* Windows quirks (malformed application window), I ended up using `ShellExecute`. That gives me enough flexibility to achieve exactly what I want at some expense...

Comment: If you want to do it via system() you would have to invoke `cmd /c start whatever` and perhaps need to specify the full path to cmd.exe.  I think ShellExecute() is there more elegant solution, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why don't you just use Qt's support for this? For example:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("/home/realnc/test.pdf"));
```

This opens the document in Acrobat Reader. In general, it obeys the preferred application settings in my OS for all file types that have one or more applications associated with them. Best of all, it's platform-independent.

Edit:
The fact that it opens directories on Linux but not on Windows smells like a bug. It might be best to report this on [Qt's bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt-project.org). In the meantime, you could have a workaround for Windows for when the file is a directory:

```
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
    if (QFileInfo(path).isDir())
        QProcess::startDetached("explorer", QStringList(path));
    else
#endif
        QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl(path));
```

You can also do it with cmd.exe's start command, but you'll get an ugly terminal pop up for a few fractions of a second:

```
QProcess::startDetached("cmd", QStringList() << "/C" << "start"
                               << QDir::toNativeSeparators(path));
```

Comment: Thanks! Please check my updated question: It doesn't work for directories on Windows.

Comment: OK, thanks, upvoted! Unfortunately, that brings up a malformed explorer window (Windows bug?) but there is not much you can do about it. (Passing a `/root` flag to `explorer` resolves that issue.)

Comment: @Ali I also posted code to do this with the `start` command (though, as noted, you get a commandline window popping up and out.)

Comment: `cmd /C start` doesn't work on my machine. I get the command line window then nothing happens. I double-checked it with your code too. Any ideas?

Comment: @Ali `start` needs an argument. For example `start C:\\`. The code I posted reflects that.

Comment: I ran your code exactly as you had posted it. It doesn't work on my machine.

Comment: @Ali Hm. I'm on Windows 7 x64. What Windows version are you on?

Comment: WinXP SP2, Qt 4.7.4, 32 bit. Doesn't matter. Even if it worked it would bring up a malformed window due to the hard-coded constant passed by Qt, I checked the latest source code.